# Transferring Data Both Ways Between Parent and Child Popup Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, popupwindow

I have spent a couple of days looking for something to accomplish my needs, and I have been unable to find it.

I have a basic HTML input box in a parent window that has text in it (from a MySQL query). I need to be able to generate a popup window that shows a textarea which contains this same text. I would then need to be able to edit the text in the textarea, press a button, and have it close the window, and send the text back to the parent window's input box.

I am indifferent to the use of jquery, as I am already loading it for other elements on the page. I just want whatever works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not creating a popup, but creating one with a textarea that updates an input box on the parent.

Comment: Do you mean like this: https://jsfiddle.net/57r4zhoj/3/

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. Thank you so much. You should make your comment an answer.